# How to change top links

Tags: magento

I'm trying to change the top links list on header, such as addLink, removeLink, etc. So I create an observer which catch event "controller_front_send_response_before", and add this:

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();    
$layout->getBlock('top.links')->addLink('hi','test','the');
```

But the top links stay the same. It worked if I do it in layout xml file like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink">
            <label>hi</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Please help, I need to do it programmatically, so I can add some conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`

Comment: Can you tell me which class should my observer extends? Because when I use your mentioned event, it said ` Call to a member function addLink() on a non-object`. I guess `$this->getLayout();` not worked anymore

Comment: you can use Mage::app()->getLayout() to access the layout object

Comment: Okay, I changed the event to `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` and it worked